# My css doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, css

I am so curious to discover where is my wrong in my simple project HTML and CSS.

My aside doesn't works with my modifications in "file.css", however another components of html works normaly when I change the "file.css". I just tried to change my code many times, for example with:
.navegacao-site li , .navegacao-site a , nav li , nav a , aside a , aside li,but othing wors. Follow my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <title class="título">Studio Platinum</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="img/logo2.jpg">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div>
                <img class="logoStudioPlatinum" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo do Studio Platinum
            </div>
            <h1>Studio Platinum</h1>


        <aside> 
            <nav class="navegacao-site">
                <ul >
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a></li>
                    <li><a href="produtos.html">Produtos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </aside>

            <div class="secao-rodape secao-informacoes">
                <h2>Informações</h2>
                <a href="#/contato.html">Nossa Equipe</a>
                <a href="#/index.html">Horario de Funcionamento</a>
                <a href="#/contato.html">Fale Conosco</a>
            </div>
            <div class="secao-rodape secao-localizacao">
                <h2>Localização</h2>
                <p>Studio Platinum</p>
                <p>Rua doSenhor do Roubado, n15</p>
                <p>Telefone: 215 689 752</p>
            </div>
            <div class="secao-rodape secao-saiba-mais">
                <p>Studio Platinum de Odivelas</p>
                <p>O salão com mais likes</p>
                <p>do facebook desta zona</p>
                <button class="button-saiba-mais">Saiba Mais</button>
            </div>
            <div class="secao-rodape secao-facebook">
                <h2>Siga-nos no facebok:</h2>
                <img class="logo-facebook" src="img/Facebook.png" alt="siga a pagina do Studio Platinum no facebook">
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <div class="rodape">
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.logoStudioPlatinum{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1em solid #b106ff;
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
}
body{
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
}
h1{
    float: left;
    color: #000;    
}
.navegacao-site li {
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
    background-color: #7C3D99 !important;
    border: 2px solid #b106ff;
    font-family: serif ;
    margin:  .4em;
    padding: .5em;
    text-align: left;
    width: 6em;
    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
    color: #FFF !important;
}

.navegacao-site a{
    color: rgba(99, 170, 140, 0.747);
}
.navegacao-site{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0%;
    top: 30%;
}
.logo-facebook{
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    right: 30%;
    bottom: 10%;
}
.secao-saiba-mais{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    right: 25%;
}
.secao-saiba-mais p{
    text-align: center;
}
.button-saiba-mais{
    color: white;
    background-color: #7C3D99;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
    padding: .5em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 37%;
    bottom: 5%;

}
.rodape{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50%;
    display: block;
}
.secao-rodape{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
    height: 10em;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.secao-rodape a, .secao-rodape p{
    display: block;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: .5em;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.secao-rodape h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1em;
}
.secao-rodape .secao-rodape a{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #7C3D99;
    padding: .5em;
    margin-top: 3em;
}
.secao-facebook{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
}
.secao-localiacao{
    right: 50%;
}
```

Thank you advanced.

Comment: Which css file includes the css content you posted? Where is file.css?

Comment: You have a typo in your example: `<img class="logoStudioPlatinum" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo do Studio Platinum` Not sure if that's stopping some CSS from applying, but you need to close your `img` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here

```
<div>
    <img class="logoStudioPlatinum" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo do Studio Platinum
</div>
```

You are missing a **">** at the end of `alt="logo do Studio Platinum`
putting in these things would make it work, correct form would be:

```
<div>
    <img class="logoStudioPlatinum" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo do Studio Platinum">
</div>
```